# getting top row of joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables, tableA and tableB

```
tableA - id int
         name varchar(50)

tableB - id int
         fkid int
         name varchar(50)
```

Both tables are joined between id and fkid.

Below are sample rows from tableA

[image]

Below is output from tableB
[image]

I want to join both tables and get only top row of joined table. So output will be like below

```
Id          Name         fkid
 1          P1              1
 2          P2              4
 3          P3            null
```

Here is [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f09aa/2)

How can i achieve this with single query? I know that i can loop through in my .net code and retrieve top rows. But i want it in single query.

Comment: what do you mean you want the top row? you've showed the expected output with 3 rows not 1, so what exactly do you want?

Comment: @DanielAndré I said top row from joined table and not whole output with just 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ta.id, ta.name, min(tb.id) from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on tb.fkid=ta.id
group by ta.id, ta.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.id,a.name,b.fid from tableA a left join 
(
select min(id) fid ,fkid from tableB  group by fkid
)b
on a.id = b.fkid
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fkID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNbr,
        tableB.*
    FROM
        tableB
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableA
    LEFT JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.fkID=tableA.id
        AND CTE.RowNbr=1
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f09aa/16)

Or without window function. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableA
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fkID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNbr,
            tableB.*
        FROM
            tableB
    ) as tbl
    ON tbl.fkID=tableA.id
    AND tbl.RowNbr=1
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f09aa/13)

**Update:**

The reason why I choose to do it with row_number is that if there is more columns in tableB then the example. Then there is no need for additional aggregate if you want to show more columns. For me personally it is more clear with an order by on the ID

Comment: The query written by @Danila is simpler. Any specific reason to use Row_Number? Your query also gives correct output

Comment: No there are not more columns. Also its bit difficult to convert your query to linq. Do you think its easy to convert  your query to linq?